# My file is reinfected as soon as I chown back to user:psacln

Tags: linux, php, malware

I can turn off write permissions on the directory and remove the file using `rm -v filename`. I can recreate the file using `touch filename` and even add contents using `nano filename`. But, as soon as I `chown user:psacln filename` the file is reinfected immediately.

By reinfected, I mean the contents of the file are changed and permissions are changed to 444. I use Plesk to host the website where the file is located. The website is a WordPress site. WP, themes and plugins are up to date.

Comment: Exactly what does "reinfected" mean: data corruption, file removed, timestamp changed, ownership change, permissions changed ? And what users are in the group `psacln`. For what purpose are you using `Plesk`, and how is it configured ?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: @Paul_Pedant I have edited my original post. There are no users in the `psacln` using `grep 'psacln' /etc/group`

Comment: "_By reinfected, I mean the contents of the file are changed_" - infection has a particular meaning. Why do you think it's an infection? What are the new contents of the file?

Comment: Plesk has had several CVEs over the last couple of months; WP is not exactly renowned for good security ... I'd take the machine off-line, reinstall with latest versions, do some hardening and restore data from your last known-good backup.

Comment: @roaima The contents are prepended with a base64 string eval-ed to `gzinflate` and `strrev`.

Comment: @tink thank you for this advice

Comment: [How do I deal with a compromised server?](https://security.stackexchange.com/q/39231/77217)

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it should rather be asked at [Cybersecurity SE](https://security.stackexchange.com).

Answer (score 0):

Malware in your Wordpress website is scanning your directories and files constantly. It runs from the webserver, so whenever you grant the webserver file access permission, it can modify the file. The cause is not Plesk, but malware in your website, e.g. a malicious plugin or theme. You can try to use ImmunifyAV that is available as a Plesk extension to remove it, or better remove the whole website and rebuild with using secure, reknown plugins and themes only.